# Почему не применяются изменения в _pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py?

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

Следовал по [этой](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DeployExistingDjangoProject/) инструкции.

```
(myenv) 13:17 ~/1website_v1 (master)$ pwd
/home/Goganoid/1website_v1
(myenv) 13:17 ~/1website_v1 (master)$ ls
README.md  db.sqlite3  jinjalesson  learntime  manage.py  media  static  tinymce  webexample
(myenv) 13:17 ~/1website_v1 (master)$
```

В learntime находится settings.
Так выглядит мой _pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py:

```
HELLO_WORLD = """<html>
<head>
    <title>Python Anywhere hosted web application</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello, World!</h1>
<p>
    This is the default welcome page for a
    <a href="https://www.pythonanywhere.com/">PythonAnywhere</a>
    hosted web application.
</p>
<p>
    Find out more about how to configure your own web application
    by visiting the <a href="https://www.pythonanywhere.com/web_app_setup/">web app setup</a> page
</p>
</body>
</html>"""


def application(environ, start_response):
    if environ.get('PATH_INFO') == '/':
        status = '200 OK'
        content = HELLO_WORLD
    else:
        status = '404 NOT FOUND'
        content = 'Page not found.'
    response_headers = [('Content-Type', 'text/html'), ('Content-Length', str(len(content)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)
    yield content.encode('utf8')


# Below are templates for Django and Flask.  You should update the file
# appropriately for the web framework you're using, and then
# click the 'Reload /yourdomain.com/' button on the 'Web' tab to make your site
# live.

# +++++++++++ VIRTUALENV +++++++++++
# If you want to use a virtualenv, set its path on the web app setup tab.
# Then come back here and import your application object as per the
# instructions below


# +++++++++++ CUSTOM WSGI +++++++++++
# If you have a WSGI file that you want to serve using PythonAnywhere, perhaps
# in your home directory under version control, then use something like this:
#
#import sys
#
#path = '/home/Goganoid/path/to/my/app
#if path not in sys.path:
#    sys.path.append(path)
#
#from my_wsgi_file import application  # noqa


# +++++++++++ DJANGO +++++++++++
# To use your own django app use code like this:
import os
import sys

# assuming your django settings file is at '/home/Goganoid/mysite/mysite/settings.py'
# and your manage.py is is at '/home/Goganoid/mysite/manage.py'
path = '/home/Goganoid/1website_v1'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'learntime.settings'

# then:
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Сайт я перезапускал.
Но выдает ошибку somethin went wrong.
Вот ошибка из errorlog'а:

```
2018-07-18 12:19:25,781: Error running WSGI application
2018-07-18 12:19:25,789: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '1website_v1.settings'
2018-07-18 12:19:25,789:   File "/var/www/goganoid_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 22, in <module>
2018-07-18 12:19:25,789:     application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Почему используется путь '1website_v1.settings', а не 'learntime.settings'?
Где я мог накосячить и как фиксится?
P.S. я даже папку переименовывал  '1website_v1' в другое, а ошибка с тем же текстом

Comment: Проблема фиксится удалением всех файлов в вкладке files